# session data not displaying on logging in once but its displaying once logging out and logging in again

Tags: php, session-variables

session data not displaying on logging in for the 1st time but its displaying once logging out and logging in again.

Anything can i do to display session data on example.com/page2.php on logging in for the first time ?

> **example.com/page1.php**

```
<?php
session_start();                    
                    $_SESSION['id'] = 1;
                    $_SESSION['name'] = 'dummy name';
                    $_SESSION['email'] = 'dummy@dummymail.com';

header("Location: http://example.com/page2.php");
?>
```

> **example.com/page2.php**

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://example.com/page1.php' )

{   

   ob_start();
   session_start();
   echo $_SESSION['id'];
   echo $_SESSION['name'];
   echo $_SESSION['email'];
}
?>

<a href = 'example.com/logout.php'>Logout</a>
```

> **example.com/logout.php**

```
<?php
session_destroy();
header("Location: http://example.com/page1.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call

```
session_write_close();
```

before

```
header("Location: ...");
```

to ensure that the session data set in page 1 is written to disk before page 2 is requested.

In addition, it seems that using

```
header("Location: ...");
```

on page 1 will leave the $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] value unset on page2.php. I tested this by changing page2.php to

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($_SERVER, true));
    echo "</pre>";
    if ($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] == "http://example.com/page1.php")
    {
        session_start();
        echo $_SESSION["id"];
        echo $_SESSION["name"];
        echo $_SESSION["email"];
    }
?>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

If you try the same you may see that

```
[HTTP_REFERER] => http://example.com/page1.php
```

is not listed in the $_SERVER array on page 2.

On page 1, just to test, instead of using

```
header("Location: ...");
```

try using

```
echo '<a href="page2.php">Page 2</a>';
```

and you should find that when you request page1.php then click on the Page 2 link, $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] value will be set on page 2.

So is seems that your problem may include redirection not setting $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]. Once you change your scripts to resolve this issue you may have a better change or sorting out the session issue.

You might like to try

page1.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["id"] = 1;
    $_SESSION["name"] = "Dummy";
    $_SESSION["email"] = "dummy@example.com";
    session_write_close();
    header("Location: page2.php");
?>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION["id"]) && ($_SESSION["id"] == 1))
    {
        echo $_SESSION["id"];
        echo $_SESSION["name"];
        echo $_SESSION["email"];
        echo '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'You are not logged in. <a href="page1.php">Login</a>';
    }
?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_write_close();
    echo 'You have been logged out. <a href="page1.php">Login</a> <a href="page2.php">Test login status</a>';
?>
```

Comment: its still not working. Placed session_write_close(); before header in page1.php but its still not working.

Comment: Add session_write_close before header("Location: ...") in logout page also (to ensure the cleared session is also written to disk).

Comment: Also, I would replace session_destroy(); with $_SESSION = array(); before session_write_close(); in the logout page.

Comment: Yes I added session_write_close() before header("Location:..") in logout.php too but my problem is still the same. when I close and start the browser again, session data not displaying in page2.php on logging in for the 1st time but its displaying once logging out and logging in again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the guidance. I spent 13 hours yesterday to solve the problem. And it is solved now following your code. I must ensure every time that session_start() is the 1st line in the PHP code and checking if session variable is set when displaying session data.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is necroing a 4 year old thread, and you were not having the exact situation but here's what I found:

I was having a problem with my welcome message saying 'Welcome, [user]!'. I couldn't get it to display until I logged out and logged in again, similar to your question title.

```
       <?php 
            //says "Welcome, (whatever the user's name is)!"
            $welcomemessage = "Welcome, " . $_SESSION["user"] . "!";
            if ($_SESSION["loggedIn"] === 'y') {
            echo $welcomemessage; }
       ?>
```

On my change username page, I changed the session variable to my new username, like so:

```
$_SESSION["user"] = $newusername;
```

which is changing it from the initial username, since your old username would be set as the current session variable even if you've changed it.

So, if I change my username from John to Jeff, anything which would mention John will be changed to Jeff immediately as the 'new username' variable is displayed, rather than having to log out then log in for the code to take your new username from the database and display it.

I know this won't help you as it's been 4 years, but this was the closest question I could find to my problem and wanted to share my simple solution for anyone else who looks this up :)

Comment: thanks for an answer but to be honest, this questions is so old that I don't even remember where I was facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `session_start()` on your `logout.php`.

```
<?php
session_start(); //<------- Here
session_destroy();
header("Location: http://example.com/page1.php");
?>
```

and comment this on `page2.php`

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://example.com/page1.php' )

{   

   ob_start();
   //session_start();  <----- Comment this as shown
   echo $_SESSION['id'];
   echo $_SESSION['name'];
   echo $_SESSION['email'];
}
?>

<a href = 'example.com/logout.php'>Logout</a>
```

Comment: Is it required in logout.php ? Because im destroying the session that is already started.